# The ë character becomes a symbol when imported with a query

Tags: php, html, mysql, sql, character-encoding

Alright so I have got a database that contains data of some different countries such as capital, continent, population. In my language, the continent Asia is translated to Azië. But when I import the data through a query it displays it like this: Azi�

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Opdracht 36</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
  </head>
  <body>
    <table>
      <tr>
        <strong>
          <th>land_id</th>
          <th>land</th>
          <th>hoofdstad</th>
          <th>werelddeel</th>
          <th>inwoners</th>
        </strong>
      </tr>
      <?php 
        $servername = "localhost";
        $username = "root";
        $password = "";
        mysql_connect($servername, $username, $password);
        mysql_select_db("Enigma");
        $query = "SELECT * FROM landen ORDER BY werelddeel";
        $result = mysql_query($query);
        while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) 
        {
      ?>
      <tr>
        <td><?php echo $row["land_id"]; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $row["land"]; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $row["hoofdstad"]; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $row["werelddeel"]; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $row["inwoners"]; ?></td>
      </tr>
      <?php
        }
      ?>
    </table>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: oops the code got messed up let me fix it

Comment: I just fixed the code if you could refresh the page and help me with what I should change?

Comment: Click that link. Your DB connection should be UTF8, your DB should be UTF8, the webpage should be utf8, the page where you wrote the data from should be sending it as utf8.

Comment: Read about [_black diamond_](http://stackoverflow.com/a/38363567/1766831)